# Pass results of `find` to jest (via npm script)

Tags: command-line, bash

**Scenario**

I am using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) and [nodejs](https://nodejs.dev/) to run javascript unit tests for a project. I'm using [git](https://git-scm.com/) and as part of a pre-commit [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) I only want to run SOME tests (the really fast ones) and then the rest of the tests will run as part of the cicd pipeline.

Currently I'm adding `pre-` to the name of my pre-commit tests and am attempted to run only those with

```
find test/ -iname "pre-*.js" | npm test
```

Which isn't work because I don't know how to "pipe" into an npm script command

```
"test": "env-cmd -f .env.test ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
```

**Question**

How can I pass my results from `find` into `npm test` ?

Answer (score 0):

While writing/researching this I found an answer citing "[magic incantation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28775887/332578)" which is what ended up working for me:

```
"test:pre": "npm test -- test/pre-*test.js",
```

*the "magic" part is after the `--`*